# Create new instance class reference

Tags: java, java-8

I have an Enum like this:

```
public static enum TestEnum {
    // main
    ENUM_A  (1, "test1", TestADto.class),
    ENUM_B  (2, "test2", TestBDto.class),
    ENUM_C  (3, "test3", TestCDto.class),
    ...

    private Class<? extends Dto> dtoClass;

    public Class<? extends Dto getDtoClass() {
        return dtoClass;
    }

    ...
}
```

All of these dto classes extend the same abstract (dto) class:

```
public abstract class AbstractDto {

    private String foo;

    private int bar;

    ...

    AbstractDto(AbstractClassNeededForInitialization o) {
        this.foo = o.getFoo();
        this.bar = o.getBar();
    }

    ... some functions here ...
}
```

This would a example Dto implementation of TestADto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestADto extends AbstractDto {

    private String anotherFoo;

    private int anotherBar;

    ...

    public TestADto(AbstractClassNeededForInitialization o) {
        super(o);
    }

    ... some functions here ...
}
```

Is it possible (im using Java 8) create a concrete instance of these in the enum reference classes without the need of knowing which concrete istance it is?

Lets say im at a certain point in a function and im having the Enum_A. Now i want to create a dto instance (TestADto.class). What would be the best approach or pattern for this?

Imagine a enum with more than 100 entries and every entry has a different dto which extends the same abstract dto or implements a interface.

How can i create these concrete object without writing a huge if else or switch statement or handle it case by case.

I read something about reflection and proxies but not sure if this is the right way i am. Or is the current state im having already a kind of poor design?
Everything i want to reach is to assign the dto name to an enum for creating it later at some certain points. But without creating a huge condition if possible...

**@Edit**

I forgot to mention that creating a instance of each dto needs to have object which is passed to the constructor. This object which is passed to the constructor also implements a interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to invoke an empty constructor for your DTO subclasses, you could provide a `Supplier` in the enum constructor that you store in a field :

```
...
ENUM_A  (1, "test1", TestADto::new),
ENUM_B  (2, "test2", TestBDto::new),
ENUM_C  (3, "test3", TestCDto::new);

private Supplier<Dto> supplierDto;

TestEnum(int i, String name, Supplier<Dto> supplierDTO){
    this.supplierDto = supplierDTO;
    ...
}
...
```

Then you can create the Dto instance by invoking  `supplierDto.get();`

---

After your edit :

> I forgot to mention that creating a instance of each dto needs to have
>   object which is passed to the constructor.

A `Supplier<Dto>` doesn't suit any longer as it is not designed to be used with a constructor that presents one parameter.

By Supposing that your constructors are like that :

```
public class TestADto{
    ...
   private MyInterface myInterface;

   public TestADto (MyInterface myInterface){
       this.myInterface = myInterface;
   }
    ...    
}
```

You could so declare in the enum constructor a `Function <MyInterface, Dto>` parameter to match to this constructor.

```
...
ENUM_A  (1, "test1", TestADto::new),
ENUM_B  (2, "test2", TestBDto::new),
ENUM_C  (3, "test3", TestCDto::new);

private Function <MyInterface, Dto> dtoConstructor;

TestEnum(int i, String name, Function <MyInterface, Dto> dtoConstructor){
    this.dtoConstructor = dtoConstructor;
    ...
}

public Dto createInstance(MyInterface myInterface){
    return myInterfaceToDtoFunction.apply(myInterface);
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks david....and sorry for editing the original post so many times! :-)

Comment: @StephanM You are welcome and don't worry, I am sure that the next time you would be initially more precise :)

Comment: @Michael Ah ok. I get what you mean. In fact, I would like to write something similar enough to some built-in functional interfaces such as `IntToLongFunction`. But I agree that `constructor` is better as it is more specific. While it stays still a little too generalist. I think that`dtoConstructor` would be a still better choice as reading `dtoConstructor.apply(myInterface);` conveys straight that the method do.

Answer (score 7):

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45715655/1898563) was almost there, but you said the constructor requires a parameter, so I'd do this. For the purposes of this example, I've assumed your constructors take a String:

```
ENUM_A  (1, "test1", TestADto::new),
ENUM_B  (2, "test2", TestBDto::new),
ENUM_C  (3, "test3", TestCDto::new);

private final Function<String, Foo> constructor;

TestEnum(int i, String name, Function<String, Foo> constructor){
    this.constructor = constructor;
}

public Dto getInstance(final String argument)
{
    return constructor.apply(argument);
}
```

Comment: I like your way the reflection way doesn't saving anything, since the OP want to list all types by enum and `TestADao::new` is shorter than `TestADao.class`.

Comment: @holi-java Plus, this is Java 8. If you're not using method references, functional interfaces, and streams in every class then the compiler will make fun of you behind your back.

Comment: the OP changed the requirement after my answer was submitted. And I don't watch all edits. Therefore, yes it doesn't match totally :-)

Comment: Thanks Michael! davidxxx's solution was slightly more clear to me but this was also my fault as i was editing my post several times. Anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use reflection on the Class object returned by the `getDtoClass()` method of the `TestEnum` instance you got in hand. The method [`Class#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) will create an instance of any class object you have.

This solution makes the assumption that there is a zero argument constructor visible in all the classes you'd reference in the enum - thanks to @Michael for pointing that out. If this is not the case, you can still use reflection but might want to check out the [`Constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) accessor class, which offers more powerful access to all the constructors in a class. This [nice tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) explains the advantages of Constructor in more detail.

Using reflection when needed also has the distinct advantage of being inherently lazy. The instance will only be created when needed, as opposed to instanciating all classes when initializing the enum class.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider that AbstractDTO is the class from which all your DTO classes extend. 
Then in your Enum instead of storing a reference to Class of DTO, store a reference to the object of the intended DTO. Something like shown below

```
public static enum TestEnum {
    ENUM_A  (1, "test1", new TestADto()),
    ENUM_B  (2, "test2", new TestBDto()),
    ENUM_C  (3, "test3", new  TestCDto()),
    ...
    private AbstractDTO dto;

    TestEnum (arg1,arg2, AbstractDTO desiredDTO) {
       this.dto = desiredDTO;
    }

    public AbstractDTO getDto() {
       return dto ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not possible cause the constructor of each dto needs a object....

Comment: I believe you would have received your answer already, however I am not sure if I understood "constructor of each dto needs a object" ? Do you mean new TestADto() would need to be passed some parameters ?